# How to create filters for a site in figma?

Tags: user-interface, web, user-experience, figma, google-web-designer

I need to make filters according to this description:

Under the header there is a filter that filters the following values:
a. Dates: "from - to"
b. Tour type – World / City
c. Value scale from $10 to $1500

Additional filtering options (expanded when you click on More filters):
d. Duration is the number of days/hours.
e. Languages - Russian / English.
f. Excursions – Individual / Group
g. Types of holidays - Family / Gastronomic / Fashion and vintage / Boat trips / Hunting holidays / Concerts and events / Nightlife / Sightseeing / History and architecture / Extreme holidays / Spa / Therapeutic and Ayurvedic / For children / Rooftops and panoramas / Museum and art / Tasting and exhibitions / VIP-rest / Other
h. Mode of transport – Walking / Train / Motorcycle / Segway / Car / Bus / Bicycle / Rollers / Air flight / Ship / Public transport / Other.

- Each item is separated by a bar, a tick is used to select a value.
- "Cancel" button and "Apply filters" button.
- Sort by Rating and Price.
- Next to the filter, place a search by tags and a list of tags (italy, montenegro, sea, maldives, vietnam, morocco, yachting, sicily, mountains, ukraine, moto).

I'm a beginner figma user so I don't know how to implement this